# Acceder a la propiedad próxima en un JSON en angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Quiero obtener de alguna manera en la vista de AngularJS (Angular 1) los valores que están en la llave de "tipo_contenido", específicamente quiero obtener "articulos", "informacion", quiero obtener estas claves, pero no sé desde el ng-repeat como ponerlas. Por cierto mi código puede ser dinámico, y con esta estructura puedo tener más elementos,  entonces me serviría quemar posiciones.

```
$scope.aTiposUsuarios=
     [
       {
         "tipo_usuario": "administrador", 
         "tipo_contenido":{
          "articulos":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true},
          "informacion":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true}
         }     
       },
      {
         "tipo_usuario": "reportante", 
         "tipo_contenido":{
          "articulos":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true},
          "informacion":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true}
         }     
       }
     ]        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a0j2uys4/

Answer (score 0):

conozco esta forma de hacerlo, no se si es lo que necesitas...

```
          angular.forEach($scope.aTiposUsuarios, function(value, key){
               angular.forEach(value,function(value2, key2){
                     if(key2=="tipo_contenido"){
                        angular.forEach(value2,function(value3, key3){
                           console.log(' Key3: '+key3);
                        })
                     }
              })
         })
```

Comment: en JavaScript es muy recomendable utilizar los 3 signos de igualdad: if (key2==="tipo_contenido"){

Comment: hay que tener cuidado con `===` porque comprueba que los valores comparados sean del mismo tipo de variable. Es decir si tengo `var v1 = "1"` y quiero hacer una comparación solo para saber si vale 1 de la siguiente forma `v1 === 1` esto me dará falso.

Comment: aportando un granito de arena: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ :D